# How to send ping in C# through specific adapter?

Tags: c#, networking

I have a server with several network adapters. I need to send a ping from one of the adapters to check the connectivity.

To send ping I use System.Net.NetworkInformation Ping class. However, it looks I cannot control the adapter which is used to send the ping. If I have one adapter connected to Network A and another to Network B, how can I select the adapter to send the ping from the adapter which is connected to the specific network?

I've looked over this Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=netframework-4.8

and I couldn't find an option to specify a source address or a source adapter.

Is it possible to do using this class?

Comment: What do you want to actually check, if a host answers to a ping or if a specific interface is up?

Comment: I need to check if the link is up and ping passes.

Comment: So you actually want two different checks. For the first have a look at the [`NetworkInterface.OperationalStatus` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.operationalstatus?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The ping is sent over the most restrictive mask to the IP per IP routing rules.  So a mask with 255.255.255.0 will be selected before 255.255.0.0.

Comment: Is there any way to modify this behavior? What happens if two adapters have the same subnet mask?